# Display event details in message when attaching a task to an event

Tags: windows-10, batch, scheduled-tasks, event-viewer

When I try to safely remove hardware, Windows 10 tells me that a program is using the hardware, but doesn't tell me which program it is. I found that this information is recorded however in Event Viewer under System as Event 225 as such:

> The application \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Program Files... with process id 4424 stopped the
>   removal or ejection for the device
>   USB....

This is pretty helpful information that I would like to see without going to event viewer every time. I have found that there is a button in Event Viewer which states Attach Task To This Event... When pressed, it offers the option to display a message every time this event is logged. I would like to have the task display the event details every time the event 225 gets logged. It seems like it could be possible, but I'm not a system level expert.

Is there an easy way to accomplish my goal? If not in the display message, is there a way to script a batch file to execute instead to tell me this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "display a message" action is deprecated and might not actually do anything. Instead, you can use PowerShell! Save this as a `.ps1` file somewhere on the computer, e.g. `C:\evtmsg.ps1`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$lastEvt = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'System' -MaxEvents 20 | ? { $_.Id -eq 225 } | select -First 1
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(($lastEvt.Message), 'Ejection Failed')
```

This script gets the most recent instance of event 225 from the System log and uses the Windows Forms library to display its message.

Use Event Viewer's *Attach Task To This Event* command on an instance of event 225. On the Action screen, choose "start a program," then specify `powershell` for the program/script to run. In the "add arguments" box, put this line, adjusted for where you saved the PowerShell script:

```
-executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -file C:\evtmsg.ps1
```

The change should take effect immediately after creating the task.

Answer (score 1):

### Send email notification when specific Event ID is generated

I have a similar solution I wanted to share just in case someone can put it to use since it seems to help me out and scream at me only when I explicitly need it to based on specific **Event IDs**.

> ### Scheduling
>
> This solution uses a **Task Scheduler** job that has many different
>   **Triggers** of the **On an event** for when it is to execute. You specify the specific **Event ID** that's to "*trigger*" an execution.
>
> [image] 
>   [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### PowerShell Script
>
> Here's a **PowerShell** script that uses a Gmail account with a
>   password to send an email which will include the detail of the
>   applicable events in its body.
>
> **Note:** *You have to pass the Gmail account password as the first argument to the PowerShell script.*
>
> ```
> $EmailPassword=$args[0]
> $event = get-eventlog -LogName System -EntryType Error -newest 1
>
> $PCName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
> $Username = "LocalMailBox"
> $EmailBody = $event | format-list -property * | out-string
> $EmailFrom = "$PCName <noreply@domain.notify>"
> $EmailTo = "whatever@gmail.com" 
> $EmailSubject = "New Event Log [System]"
> $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
> Write-host "Sending Email"
> $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
> $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
> $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $EmailPassword); 
> $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $EmailSubject, $EmailBody)
> Start-Sleep -s 10
> ```
>
> From the **Action** tab you will create an **Action** defined as:
>
> - **Action:** `Start a program`
> - **Program/script:** `Powershell`
> - **Add arguments (optional):** `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Scripts\PSScript.ps1" "GmailPassword"`
> - **Start in (optional):** `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` 
>     [image]
>
> From the **General** tab of the scheduled task, be sure the **Run
>   whether user is logged on or not** and the **Run with highest
>   privileges** options are both selected.
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### The Email
>
> With everything listed above set just as specified, this will ensure
>   that when those specific **System Event IDs** are generated which you
>   defined "*triggers*"  for that an email will be sent, and hopefully
>   with applicable detail as per the event that triggers each.
>
> I only mention this as I have noticed that if two event that match the
>   **PowerShell** logic of `$event | format-list -property * | out-string` are created quickly, that the body of the email will
>   contain the latest event's detail based on timing.
>
> Remember that regardless of the **Event ID** body content and even if
>   it's not pertinent to the specific events you defined as triggers it
>   is certain that those defined triggered indeed triggered this email so
>   give it some attention when received.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While I was not quite looking for an email (since this is meant for my pc rather than a remote server), I have actually learned quite a bit from your answer. Especially that there is another side to windows which allows me to customize it quite a bit! I think I'll have a bit of fun in the next while exploring this.