# Email Notifications On Program Install

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to use the task scheduler on windows to receive an email notification every time a program is installed? If so, how? Right now, I have a Task setup to notify when there is a login that uses the sendEmail application from Brandon Zehm, and I like that style, so if I could use that...

Comment: Well, program installations are a pretty nebulous thing. Some just require you to copy some files to a folder. Catching that would be tricky. A best effort method would be to register a WMI event sink that would fire whenever the uninstall registry key changes. Be sure to cover the 32 bit and 64 bit keys both.

Comment: Oh.... you can use this method just as I wrote about in this post https://superuser.com/questions/1309840/display-event-details-in-message-when-attaching-a-task-to-an-event/1309955#1309955 but use the "Application" event log (i.e. `$event = get-eventlog -LogName Application ~`) and set it to look for Event ID [`11707`](http://www.eventid.net/display-eventid-11707-source-MsiInstaller-eventno-1514-phase-1.htm) and [`1003`](http://www.eventid.net/display.asp?eventid=1033&source=)....

Comment: This will send an email with that method when those events are generated and trigger the script to run. You could use the sendemail app with this rather than the PowerShell method as I use that command line for a lot of automated processes too and I wrote about that here https://superuser.com/questions/1023295/automatically-send-multiple-emails-from-outlook-at-specific-times/1023336#1023336 a while back but you could incorporate this to be run instead of the PowerShell method but it works just as well from my experience and I use sendemail a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as Pimp Juice said, I would look for the event log (see down the page https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_detect_software_installations.html) and then to send an email read this (http://www.dummies.com/computers/pcs/how-to-create-a-task-to-send-e-mail-in-windows-task-scheduler/)

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I just modified the instructions from the netwrix article to send the email. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great; Glad to help :-)

Comment: Actually, on Stack Exchange we want to use links only as reference. Everything should be explained within the answer.